# Guardar texto de textbox (String) en una variable string C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un formulario donde tengo un textbox y un boton. El textbox permite la entrada de datos y al presionar el boton quiero que se guarde el texto del textbox en un string. El problema radica que al obtener el texto es de tipo String,  y no se como convertirlo a string.
Aca les dejo el codigo para que me ayuden.
Gracias.

textbox1->Text; //Obtengo el texto....................................................................................................
Se guarda de esta manera...............................................................................................................
String ^ n;.............................................................................................................................................
n = textbox1->Text;........................................................................................................................
Pero yo deseo guardarlo o convertirlo a string.............................................................................................................................................
string g;................................................................................................................................................
g = textbox1->Text;
[image]

Comment: ¿ Que lenguaje es ese ? Porque `C++` **no es** :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un ciclo `for` para recorrer el `System:String^` y añadirlo a tu `std::string`

```
String^ aux = textBox1->Text;

for (int i = 0; i < aux->Length; i++)
{
    dato += (char)aux[i];
}
```

Si esto lo vas a tener que hacer muchas veces, te recomiendo que hagas una función.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, me ayudó bastante y si implemente una función para usarlo varias veces.

Comment: Para eso estamos :D, si puedes, intenta marcar la respuesta como correcta, para que le pueda ayudar a alguien mas ;)